# Problem when to try to load to Atlas using Gazebo 2.0

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When to try to insert Atlas from Gazebo get this error:

```
Error [parser_urdf.cc:2608] Unable to call parseURDF on robot model
Error [parser.cc:273] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error [ModelMaker.cc:126] Unable to load file[/opt/ros/groovy/share/drcsim_model_resources/gazebo_models/environments/atlas_description/dummy.urdf]
```

And have problems when try to load from terminal using:

```
VRC_CHEATS_ENABLED=1 roslaunch atlas_utils atlas.launch
```

getting this error:

```
 [atlas.launch] is neither a launch file in package [atlas_utils] nor is [atlas_utils] a launch file name
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5398/problem-when-to-try-to-load-to-atlas-using-gazebo-2.0/) by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 80 on 2014-02-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The roslaunch command changed in the latest versions and now is:

> roslaunch drcsim_gazebo atlas.launch

Probably you have read an outdated documentation, could you please point me to it?
Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2014-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on 2014-02-06**:
A lot of thanks!!
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/Tutorials

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/376/vncntmh/) on 2014-02-06**:
In All the tutorials have the same problem

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/2.7/visualizing_logging_data

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/2.7/multisense_sl_data

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-02-06**:
You are right, they should be updated to version 3.3.1, thanks for the information.

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2014-05-06**:
I just fixed the refs in http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/UserGuide

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-05-08**:
Thanks very much Andrew!